# Validate if input is link

Tags: php, database, validation

I want to check if the entered is a link or not.

```
$s = $_POST['link'];
```

check if $s is a link.

Comment: by 'link' do you mean 'url' ?

Comment: What kind of link? In this format: 'http://google.com' or similar?

Comment: What do you mean by link? file:////a/ could be regarded as a link but it's not a very useful one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter_var()

```
filter_var('example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Comment: I had no idea such a thing existed. Thanks man... For those interested in more details: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways, but the most robust would be to use a regular expression to detect a URL.

Something like this would work well:

```
$pattern = '/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&amp;?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/'; 

$isLink = preg_match($pattern, $url); // Returns true if a link
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable answer for those that don't have php 5 on their server or need a more robust check on the URL compared to smott's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isValidURL($url) {
    return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}

if(!isValidURL($fldbanner_url)) {
    $errMsg .= "* Please enter valid URL including http://<br>";
}
```